# A DRCS (git, bzr, merc) that has "pending changesets" like perforce?

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs, bazaar

We have perforce at work and one thing about it really seems to work quite well with the workflow and that is pending changesets.

I can make a new pending changeset, assign changes to it, assign jira tickets to it, etc...  I can shelve files there and make other changes in other changesets.  Then when it's checkin time I can push just those changes by simply providing the changeset ID.

Do any of the main distributed revision control systems offer anything like this?  I see that most offer a variant of shelving, but pending changesets?

Edit - an example to clarify:

I have a project with files A-Z.  I do an update right before making changes for a source change I'm making.  I notice that a change I'm not ready to adopt has been made so I create a hack around it by modifying A and B.  I then make changes to files C, D, and E.

I only want to check in the latter three and I want to attach the jira ticket I'm responding to.  In p4v this is as simple as creating a new "pending changeset" and checking off the files I want in it along with the ticket number.  Then I commit my pending changeset.  I can then keep my hack around for the next run or revert it.

Comment: This sounds a lot like what you could do with most systems by creating a new branch, in which you can make one or multiple commits, then merge the branch, and finally close or delete it. Until the merge, the main branch is unaffected by the commits, but they're available to anyone who knows to specifically look at that branch / those commits. If that is not what you mean, could you explain the difference?

Comment: One big difference is that I can put different file changes into different pending changesets within the same "workspace"...what would be equivalent to a personal branch.  In other words, I can change files a.cpp, b.cpp, and c.cpp.  I can put a and b in one changeset, c in another, attach different change tickets to them, and submit them separately...but test them locally together.  I suppose there could be some way to work 3 branches to sort of get this same thing, but it doesn't sound as easy.  Plus you'd have to do that ahead of time and I can do it after the changes are made.

Answer (score 8):

Mercurial has two features that are very similar to this.  The first, and older one, is called [Mercurial Queues](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html) these are based on [Quilt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quilt_%28software%29) but are integrated into Mercurial.  That book chapter is worth reading, but they basically let you have a series of overlap changesets that can be pushed, popped, and edited willy-nilly.  They differ from shelve (git's or Mercurial's) in that they can be pushed/pulled and can actually be version controlled themself in a separate queue-specific repo.

The second, newer feature along those lines is the [Phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases) feature.  It tracks a phase for each changeset which can be `public`, `draft`, or `secret`.  The wiki page has the full details but basically `public` is anything you've pushed to another repo,`draft` is anything you haven't yet pushed (and thus can edit w/o worrying about breaking people's histories), and `private` is a changeset that won't be pushed when you `hg push`.  You can use phases along with `histedit` and `commit --amend` and even Mercurial queues to make sure a changeset doesn't leave your machine until you're happy with it.

Comment: Phases are out of game here, I suppose - changeset is immutable. MQ rocks

Comment: While it isn't currently applicable, a mention of the ongoing work towards Mercurial changeset evolution (beyond phases) might be useful.  http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangesetEvolution

Answer (score 1):

Git has the concept of [stashes](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-3.html), which are similar--you can have multiple stashes with descriptions of what's in them. The main difference is that stashes are local, while P4's pending changelists are on the server. That could be important if anyone else needs to see your pending changelists.

Comment: I believe git stashes are equivalent to p4 shelves.  You can store changes on the shelf and continue working on them (as a revert point) or revert to trunk and do something else, keeping the old changes in case what you're doing doesn't work out.  In p4 shelves can only be associated with created changesets and you have a different shelf per pending changeset.

Answer (score 1):

Git also has the concept of the index.  You can add files to the index and, by default, it only commits files that are in the index.  You can modify a number of files and put some of them in the index and leave others in the workspace.  You can even have one file modified and queued in the index and different modifications to that same file in the workspace.

Comment: ...but there's only one index. You can't (as far as I know) have multiple stacked indices which can be added to separately. That would be the equivalent if you tried to use the index in this way.

Comment: True.  I didn't see anything in the original question where he wanted to have multiple changesets queued up.  If you want to do that in git you can use stashes as @khagler suggested.